# content type description value in Content search web part

Tags: sharepoint-2013, display-templates

In content search web part using managed property (ContentType), i am able to get content type "Title" for the list items.

but my problem is i need to fetch content type "Description" not the title. I have searched for content type description managed property and i am not able to find any.

I have used rest API to get content description using content type title for the items (~100), but with this problem is, it is taking lot of time to load a page.

Please let me know if anyone have idea how to get content type Description in Display Template and it should not take time load page.

Thanks in Advance.

Milan Jain